# Copy array into another array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to copy array into another array in PHP. Then send the response as JSON output. But it copies only the last element in array multiple times. Please let me know where I am going wrong? Any help is appreciated

**PHP code**

```
stmt_bind_assoc($stmt, $resultrow);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $r[] = $resultrow;
    print_r($resultrow);
}
echo json_encode($r);
```

Output from `print_r($resultrow)`.This is correct. Values in array is different

```
Array( [a_id] => 1 [b_number] => 10101010 [dateandtime] => 2013-12-25 09:30:00 ) 
Array( [a_id] => 1 [b_number] => 20202020 [dateandtime] => 2013-12-27 11:40:00 )
```

**Output from json_encode($r)**.This is incorrect. Values in array is same

```
[{"a_id":1,"b_number":20202020,"dateandtime":"2013-12-27 11:40:00"},
 {"a_id":1,"b_number":20202020,"dateandtime":"2013-12-27 11:40:00"}]
```

Comment: You aren't using an index number in your array, you need something like $r[0] = something, $r[1] = something, .....

Comment: How is it incorrect? What would you want to obtain?

Comment: Is this your actual code? It seems like there must be something else causing the problem. You do not need to manually specify array keys, PHP increments them for you.

Comment: Does it work if you do: `stmt_bind_assoc($stmt, $resultrow);
 echo json_encode($stmt->fetchAll());`

Comment: @Jessica: it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the function `stmt_bind_assoc` from here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php#82742

Posted under that OP is:

> "...the problem is that the $row returned is reference and not data.
>   So, when you write  $array[] = $row, the $array will be filled up with
>   the last element of the dataset."

With that user's solution I came up with this to resolve your issue:

```
// replace your posted code with the following

$r = array();

// loop through all result rows
while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {

    $resultrow = array();

    foreach( $row as $key=>$value )
        $resultrow[ $key ] = $value;

    $r[] = $resultrow;

    print_r($resultrow);
}

echo json_encode($r);
```

Next time you get code from a source read the comments about the source.